# Why is the Ubuntu installation not working on a Macbook Air, while I can boot the live CD?

Tags: boot, macbook, macosx

I've got a MacBook Air mid-11 (1.6 GHz Intel Core i5, 2GB 1333 MHz DDR3 Ram).

I've downloaded Ubuntu 14.04.1 version and I've followed [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleIntelInstallation#Dual-Boot:_Mac_OSX_and_Ubuntu) to make a dual boot on my Air, with Ubuntu and OS X.

I've created a bootable USB drive to be able to boot into Ubuntu (it's the old Air's SSD). The problem is that I'm able to go into Ubuntu and test it like a live CD, but when I'm trying to install it, it gets stuck on the install screen.

[image: Example screenshot]

Do you know why I'm getting stuck? Is there any way to create a log file to upload here and see what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

If you get to the install screen it means that everything is OK. Normally such failures mean that the ISO image wasn't correctly downloaded. I would suggest to download it again and check the MD5sum of both media, that's easy : Just open a terminal and type

```
md5 whateverfile.iso
```

(Works in the same way in Linux, OS X or whatever proper operating system you can think of).

Another thing you may want to do during installation is to jump to one of the shells that are open, one of them shows the logs and there you can see what happens, this is doen with ALT+F1 and using the F-keys to switch between terminals (F6 to go back to the X server).

OR, you can open a terminal and do:

```
dmesg | less -F
```

OR

```
tail -F /var/log/messages
```

BTW: The last command can also come handy for debugging issues on Mavericks,it will show you the last lines of the logs in real-time.